# Dynamic price amount from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a simple `form` including `number input`. Now, I want to dynamically add the total price, whenever someone changes the number. Could someone direct me on what to do please? I want it do be done without pressing submit.

```
<form>
<p class='ticket'>VIP ticket ($200):</p><input type="number" name="vip" min="0" max="20">
</form>

<p>Total price: </p>
```

Comment: Total is `vip` value x `$200` ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keyup & http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: Yes, the number of 1 ticket is 200$, and it will be multiplied by the number in input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your html a little:

```
<p class='ticket'>VIP ticket ($200):</p><input type="number" name="vip" id="vip" min="0" max="20" />

<p>Total price: $<span id="total">0</span></p>
```

I've used a `<span id="total"></span>` to change the total value easily, and added `id="vip"` to your number input.

```
var ticketValue = 200;

$("#vip").on("change", function() {
    $("#total").html($(this).val() * ticketValue);
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qbwo6wk/1/)**</kbd>